# Why I can't receive data from dataLayer?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Why my dataLayer is not receiving data?
In my GTM I've created a event trigger for "purchase".
Maybe there's something with structure of my dataLayer code?
I have no idea at this moment.
I would appriciate any help. Thanks in advance

Here's my frontend code:

```
<Head>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
'event': 'purchase',
'transactionId': 'transaction.id',
'transactionTotal': transaction.total,
'transactionTax': transaction.tax,
'transactionShipping': transaction.shipping,
'transactionProducts': [
  {
   'sku': 'product.id',
   'name': 'product.name',
   'category': 'product.category',
   'price': product.price,
   'quantity': product.quantity
 }
 ]
});
</script>
</Head>
```

Comment: A) That code should be in a `<script></script>` tag - is it really not, or did you just forget to paste that here? If it isn't, that is the first thing to fix. and B) Where are those variables `transaction` and `product` coming from? Order of operations matters - make sure those variables are being set before the code you pasted here runs.

Comment: Oh, yea, sorry, i forgott about that, fix it tho.

Comment: Those variables are coming from my database, and if I look up at source code of my "thank you" page, i can see that they are pased correctly, but nothing to dataLayer.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data not populating in the dataLayer code or gtm is not firing as expected?

If its gtm ensure the dataLayer is placed above the gtm container code or it cant access it.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided, it isn't clear what kind of order of operations you have.

Ideally, the order should be this

1. dataLayer declaration
2. GTM include script
3. dataLayer.push()